# Como crear un SSIS para migrar tablas maestro detalle de una base de datos a otra sin perder esa relación

Tags: ssis

tengo un incoveniente y aun no encuentro como trabajarlo, soy nuevo en el tema de SSIS y estoy haciendo un Dts para hacer una una migracion diaria de data de una base de datos (off line) a mi base de datos producción, para las tablas "normales" no hay inconvenientes pero me tope con un problema al ser tablas maestro detalle, ya que al no conservar los id's no puedo hacer la relacion entre las mismas. Es decir al insertar el maestro cada registro adquiere un nuevo id (el de la base de datos destino) y se pierde la relacion con el detalle que tiene la realcion con el id de la base de datos origen (off line).

Espero haberme podido expresar bien y agradezco cualquier ayuda para poder hacer el paso de la data de forma correcta.

Comment: ok.. ese es el problema... y las soluciones serian recomendaciones u opiniones.. yo por ejemplo, apagaria los id automaticos en la base de destino...

Comment: falta información sobre el origen de datos (SQL Server, MySQL...) y el tipo de conexión que utilizas en SSIS (OLEDB, ODBC...) pero si utilizas OLEDB y en tu dataflow usas un ole db destination, puedes marcar la opción de Keep identity para que te mantenga los ids en destino.